resources exceeded during query execution the query could not be executed in the allotted memory
I am running biquery to upload object from storage,
Bq load —source=AVRO —replace projected.mytable.abc gs://projetid/dir1/*.avro
Any idea, do I need run with any other options
Is there anyway to split or limit the storge files to upload

Firstly, the two last sentences seem identical. Secondly, the bq command would be easily read if it were delimited by backticks. Thirdly, could we see the full query that is failing eg Resources exceeded during query execution or The query could not be executed in the allotted memory
